# recoding values using wildcard

Tags: wildcard, recode

I'm trying to recode values that have certain strings in common using a wildcard, if such a thing is possible.

data format is:

Name   title
X1     Movie_1
X2     Book_1
X3     Book_2
X4     Movie_2

I want to recode: "_1" = "_1980s, "_2 = "_1990s"

I have tried:
df %>% mutate(title=recode(tite,`_1`="_1980s",`_2`="_1990s"))

It runs without error message, but makes no substitutions. I assume because it is looking for a complete string called "_1" rather than part of a string.

I installed utils package and tried the same command with '*_1' but that didn't work, either.